# Correspondence between Riemannian metrics and Euclidean embeddings

Tags: riemannian-geometry, isometry, submanifold, inverse-function-theorem

Given a sufficiently smooth manifold $M$,

- a Riemannian metric on $M$ induces an isometric embedding into Euclidean space by Nash's theorem, (non-canonically, non-uniquely)
- an embedding of $M$ into Euclidean space induces a Riemannian metric on $M$ by pullback of the induced metric. (naturally)

So, there is at least a surjection from the set of Euclidean embeddings (say, for fixed target dimension) to the set of Riemannian metrics on $M$, in the appropriate smoothness categories.

Is there more structure to this correspondence? For instance, could it be continuous in some cases, perhaps with the appropriate topologies and after appropriate quotients on the space of metrics and the space of embeddings?

The previous question [Smooth isometric embeddings of Riemannian manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362144/smooth-isometric-embeddings-of-riemannian-manifolds) notes, among other things, that the isometric embedding can be quite rigid in some cases (ex: positive curvature metrics on $S^2$ embed uniquely in $\mathbb R^3$, presumably modulo Euclidean motions).

EDIT(0): corrected per @MichaelAlbanese's initial comment.

EDIT(1): cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374097/correspondence-between-riemannian-metrics-and-euclidean-embeddings

Comment: It isn't a bijection; two different embedding can give rise to the same induced metric. For example, consider the two embeddings $T^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ given by $(a + bi, c + di) \mapsto (a, b, c, d)$ and $(a + bi, c + di) \mapsto (c, d, a, b)$.

Comment: thank you @MichaelAlbanese, you're right - I'll amend the question.

Comment: Could you say more about what you're looking for or speculating about? Let me restrict to compact manifolds (without boundary). Since the map from embeddings to Riemannian metrics is a smooth nonlinear first order differential operator, it is continuous map from $C^{k+1}$ embeddings to $C^k$ Riemannian metrics. This also implies that it's a continuous map from $C^\infty$ embeddings to $C^\infty$ metrics, using the Frechet topology. Are you asking about the existence of a continuous inverse map? Nash's theorem implies that one exists on a neighborhood of any $C^\infty$ Riemannian metric.

Comment: @Deane - thank you!  I'm wondering: (1) can the $C^0$ local inverse maps glue up to give a tractable global object, encoding info about $M$?, (2) is there a natural finite dimensional moduli space lurking?, (3) is the rigidity of $S^2\to\mathbb R^3$ for positive curvature metrics indicative of a general phenomenon?, (4) can imposing natural PDEs on either side (harmonic embeddings? Einstein metrics?) still capture most of the domain and range (mod rigid motions, mod isometries?), (5) can some finer notion of isotopy (using the metrics) encode finer structure of $M$ w.r.t. the target dimension?